# Mi app para subir ficheros no sube ficheros correctamente desde mi movil, desde mi pc si. (Ej: 30 ficheros [ 50 MB ] )

Tags: archivo, servidor, xampp, fileupload, filesystem

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web para subir imagenes, y estaba haciendo unas pruebas de rendimiento y testeando ciertas cosas.

Actualmente me encontraba haciendo unas pruebas de subidas de **30 ficheros aprox.** que ocupan **50 MB aprox.**

El servidor es un xamp local en mi pc, tiene ciertas configuraciones que le he modificado en el **php.ini**, tales como:

- *upload_max_filesize=1024M*
- *post_max_size=100M*
- *max_file_uploads=100*

En mi pc las sube todas, pero en mi movil solo sube 2 y me da un error.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Agrégalo a tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Porqué tu valor `upload_max_filesize` excede el valor de `post_max_size`? En la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) se establece que debe ser al contrario. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por responder, he conseguido resolverlo y lo he explciado por si alguien tuviera el mismo problema

Answer (score 2):

El error por lo visto no tenia que ver, *directamente* con el servidor. Aunque son necesarios esos cambios que tengo puesto en mi pregunta, el problema residia en una tabla de mi bd, pues el valor de uno de los campos excedia el valor maximo soportado por este tipo de valor.

Tenía un campo llamado *size* de tipo `float` donde almacenaba en `bytes` en tamaño de de mi archivo. Pero al guardarlo en byte los valores a veces excedian el tope de este tipado.

Entonces pase de tener un campo asi:

```
        $table->float('size');
```

a tenerlo así:

```
$table->decimal('size',50,5);
```

A lo que se traduce: un valor decimal, con una **parte entera de 50 digitos como máximo**, y un **tamaño maximo de 5 digitos en la parte decimal**.
Decir tambien que estoy usando laravel, y de ahi esa nomenclatura de las migraciones, no obstante debe de haber tipado igual si usas mysql puro